# How do I simulate session cookies for RESTful service (Grails, Shiro)?

Tags: session, grails, cookies, session-cookies, shiro

I have an existing Grails application which uses the Nimble plugin (therefore Apache Shiro security underneath).

I am adding a RESTful JSON API to it.

My `login` method manages to get the session ID from Shiro and returns it to the client:

```
class ApiController {
    def login(String username, String password) {
        def authToken = new UsernamePasswordToken(username, password)
        SecurityUtils.subject.login(authToken)

        render(contentType:"text/json") {
            [
                sessionId: SecurityUtils.subject.getSession().getId()
            ]
        }
    }

    def getData() {
        SecurityUtils.subject... // either expect to already find a properly populated SecurityUtils.subject or a way to otherwise get it
    }
}
```

This looks like:

```
{"sessionId":"61FE89F60F94A4EF7B796783E7A326BC"}
```

That is quite encouraging, as it is the same one that I see being passed in a cookie when from the browser:

```
Cookie:auth=Z3Vlc3Q6dGx1c2lz; m=2663:t|34e2:|47ba:t|4e99:t|6ef2:t|370d:t|3c0d:t|64b8:t|2a03:t|18c3:t|79d4:chart|640c:small|678e:3600%7C60|796a:t; OX_plg=swf|sl|wmp|shk|pm; _ga=GA1.1.441292120.1405856016; __atuvc=0%7C47%2C0%7C48%2C0%7C49%2C432%7C50%2C17%7C51; JSESSIONID=61FE89F60F94A4EF7B796783E7A326BC
```

However, I now cannot quite figure out how to properly pass this JSESSIONID from the mobile application in a way so that the existing Nimble / Shiro / Grails / Servlet (not sure what level) authentication filters recognize it as a proper session identifier and associate the request with the session.

I tried manually passing a Cookie with `JSESSIONID=<sessionId>` (using Dispatch on Android) but it appeared to have no effect (although perhaps my parameters to `newValidCookie` aren't all correct):

```
val cookie = com.ning.http.client.cookie.Cookie.newValidCookie("JSESSIONID", token, null, token, null, -1, -1, false, false)
val svc = host / "api" / "getData" addCookie cookie
Http(svc OK as.String)
```

I also tried to append `;jsessionid=<sessionId>` to the URL and that also did nothing.

I also tried doing `new Subject.Builder().sessionId(sessionId).buildSubject();` in the `getData()` but the `.sessionId()` there didn't like a `String`.

I haven't figured out so far where exactly the processing of the session cookie takes place.

How do I properly assemble a session cookie so that a mobile app can use the application in the same way as the web client?

P.S. My plan B is to simply pass username/password in the authentication headers upon every request and have `ApiController` do the `subject.login` every time, but I'd prefer to rather do it using the session ID that's already used for the web application.

Comment: Did you figure out something. I am also facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be something called Custom Subject Instances (https://shiro.apache.org/subject.html#custom-subject-instances)

There are two steps:

1. Create the Subject (with a Builder)
2. Associate the Subject with a thread (many ways to do this)

Untested example:

```
Serializable sessionId = //acquired from somewhere 
Subject subject = new Subject.Builder().sessionId(sessionId).buildSubject();

ThreadState threadState = new SubjectThreadState(subject);
threadState.bind();
try {
    //execute work as the built Subject
} finally {
    //ensure any state is cleaned so the thread won't be
    //corrupt in a reusable or pooled thread environment
    threadState.clear();
}
```